# I want to make an infinit card slider using framer motion

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

```
"use client"

import {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import data from '../../data.json'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { motion, useMotionValue } from 'framer-motion'
import './Trending.css'

import mv from '/public/assets/icon-category-movie.svg'
import tv from '/public/assets/icon-category-tv.svg'
import dot from '/public/assets/dot.svg'
import bookempty from '/public/assets/bookmark-empty.svg'
import bookfull from '/public/assets/bookmark-full.svg'
import play from '/public/assets/icon-play.svg'


export default function Trending() {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [isDraging, setDraging] = useState(false);

    const xposition = useMotionValue(0);
    
    const startedDraging = () => {
        setDraging(true);
    }
    const stopedDraging = () => {
        setDraging(false);

        if (xposition.get() <= -80)
            setIndex((previndex) => previndex + 1)
        else if (xposition.get() >= 80)
            setIndex((previndex) => previndex - 1)

    }

  return (
    <div className='trending-section'>
        <h1>Trending</h1>
        <motion.div 
            initial={{translateX: `-${index * 31.875}rem`}}
            className='trends'
            drag="x"
            dragConstraints={{right: 0, left: 0}}
            whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}}
            animate={{translateX: `-${index * 31.875}rem`}}
            onDragStart={startedDraging}
            onDragEnd={stopedDraging}
            style={{x: xposition}}
            >
            {
                data.filter(data => data.isTrending === true).map((movie, index) => (
                    <motion.div className='trend-card' key={index} whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}}>
                        <div className='trend-hover'>
                            <Image className='trend-banner' src={movie.thumbnail.trending.large} alt='image not found' width={470} height={230}></Image>
                            <div className='trend-infos'>
                                <p>{movie.year}</p>
                                <Image src={dot} alt='dot'></Image>
                                <div className='category'>
                                    <Image src={movie.category === "Movie" ? mv : tv} alt='tv-mv icon'></Image>
                                    <p>{movie.category}</p>
                                </div>
                                <Image src={dot} alt='dot'></Image>
                                <p>{movie.rating}</p>
                            </div>
                            <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
                            <div className='play-hover'>
                                <Image src={play} alt='play icon'></Image>
                                <h4>Play</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Image className='bookmark' src={movie.isBookmarked === true ? bookfull : bookempty} alt='bookmark'></Image>
                    </motion.div>
                ))
            }
        </motion.div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I made this card slider and it is working just fine but I can't make it infinite, like before the first card there should be the last and after the last there should be the first.

I tried rendering the 'trends' div 3 times and initializing the index with 5, and then each time the index becomes 9 or 1 I reset it to 5, but the  animation made look as it goes back to it's initial position , it does not look like an infinite slider,I also need to mention that multiple cards are displayed at the same time not just one, that what makes it even harder. So please if someone could help I will be so greatful!! I have been strungling with this for about 5 days.

```
"use client"

import {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import data from '../../data.json'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { motion, useMotionValue } from 'framer-motion'
import './Trending.css'

import mv from '/public/assets/icon-category-movie.svg'
import tv from '/public/assets/icon-category-tv.svg'
import dot from '/public/assets/dot.svg'
import bookempty from '/public/assets/bookmark-empty.svg'
import bookfull from '/public/assets/bookmark-full.svg'
import play from '/public/assets/icon-play.svg'


export default function Trending() {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(5);
    const [isDraging, setDraging] = useState(false);

    const xposition = useMotionValue(0);
    
    const startedDraging = () => {
        setDraging(true);
    }
    const stopedDraging = () => {
        setDraging(false);

        if (xposition.get() <= -80)
            setIndex((previndex) => previndex + 1)
        else if (xposition.get() >= 80)
            setIndex((previndex) => previndex - 1)
        if (index === 9 || index === 1)
            setIndex(5);

    }

  return (
    <div className='trending-section'>
        <h1>Trending</h1>
        <motion.div 
            initial={{translateX: `-${index * 31.875}rem`}}
            className='trends'
            drag="x"
            dragConstraints={{right: 0, left: 0}}
            whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}}
            animate={{translateX: `-${index * 31.875}rem`}}
            onDragStart={startedDraging}
            onDragEnd={stopedDraging}
            style={{x: xposition}}
            >
            {
                [...data, ...data, ...data].filter(data => data.isTrending === true).map((movie, index) => (
                    <motion.div className='trend-card' key={index} whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}}>
                        <div className='trend-hover'>
                            <Image className='trend-banner' src={movie.thumbnail.trending.large} alt='image not found' width={470} height={230}></Image>
                            <div className='trend-infos'>
                                <p>{movie.year}</p>
                                <Image src={dot} alt='dot'></Image>
                                <div className='category'>
                                    <Image src={movie.category === "Movie" ? mv : tv} alt='tv-mv icon'></Image>
                                    <p>{movie.category}</p>
                                </div>
                                <Image src={dot} alt='dot'></Image>
                                <p>{movie.rating}</p>
                            </div>
                            <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
                            <div className='play-hover'>
                                <Image src={play} alt='play icon'></Image>
                                <h4>Play</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Image className='bookmark' src={movie.isBookmarked === true ? bookfull : bookempty} alt='bookmark'></Image>
                    </motion.div>
                ))
            }
        </motion.div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want to achieve is not just about repeating the data, but also seamlessly transitioning between ends. This means when you reach the end of the slider, it should seamlessly transition to the beginning (and vice versa) without the user noticing.

Key point is, Instead of setting the index directly when dragging ends, we need to calculate if the drag threshold has been exceeded and update the index based on that. This makes the slider react to user interactions more naturally. We can calculate the new index using modular arithmetic. This keeps the index within bounds and allows for the infinite effect as it wraps around the dataset.

I have updated your code,

```js
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import data from '../../data.json'; 
import Image from 'next/image';
import { motion, useMotionValue } from 'framer-motion';
import './Trending.css';

import mv from '/public/assets/icon-category-movie.svg';
import tv from '/public/assets/icon-category-tv.svg';
import dot from '/public/assets/dot.svg';
import bookempty from '/public/assets/bookmark-empty.svg';
import bookfull from '/public/assets/bookmark-full.svg';
import play from '/public/assets/icon-play.svg';

export default function Trending() {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const xposition = useMotionValue(0);
    const sliderWidth = 31.875; // Width of one slide, adjust as necessary
    const totalSlides = data.filter(d => d.isTrending === true).length; // Total number of original slides

    const handleDragEnd = () => {
        // Calculate the drag distance and update the index accordingly
        const dragThreshold = 80; // Pixels required to trigger a slide change
        const newPosition = xposition.get();

        if (newPosition <= -dragThreshold) {
            setIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % totalSlides);
        } else if (newPosition >= dragThreshold) {
            setIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + totalSlides) % totalSlides);
        }

        // Reset the drag position after evaluating
        xposition.set(0);
    };

    // Clone data three times for the infinite effect
    const extendedData = [...data, ...data, ...data].filter(d => d.isTrending === true);

    return (
        <div className='trending-section'>
            <h1>Trending</h1>
            <motion.div 
                initial={{translateX: `-${index * sliderWidth}rem`}}
                drag="x"
                dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
                whileTap={{ cursor: "grabbing" }}
                animate={{ translateX: `-${index * sliderWidth}rem` }}
                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                style={{ x: xposition }}
                className='trends'
            >
                {extendedData.map((movie, idx) => (
                    <motion.div className='trend-card' key={idx} whileTap={{ cursor: "grabbing" }}>
                        <div className='trend-hover'>
                            <Image className='trend-banner' src={movie.thumbnail.trending.large} alt='image not found' width={470} height={230}></Image>
                            <div className='trend-infos'>
                                <p>{movie.year}</p>
                                <Image src={dot} alt='dot'></Image>
                                <div className='category'>
                                    <Image src={movie.category === "Movie" ? mv : tv} alt='tv-mv icon'></Image>
                                    <p>{movie.category}</p>
                                </div>
                                <Image src={dot} alt='dot'></Image>
                                <p>{movie.rating}</p>
                            </div>
                            <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
                            <div className='play-hover'>
                                <Image src={play} alt='play icon'></Image>
                                <h4>Play</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Image className='bookmark' src={movie.isBookmarked ? bookfull : bookempty} alt='bookmark'></Image>
                    </motion.div>
                ))}
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your version but it does literally the same, and we can see the animation that takes us back to the first position